# I'm trying to put an ip into the meta quest 2 browser but it is not working

Tags: browser, ip

I am trying to insert an ip into the meta quest 2 browser for the free full body thing but it will not load. When I type other things it loads. what do I do? My internet isn't the greatest but i have tried this in two places.

I have tried restarting, retyping, etc. but nothing seems to work.